# Can you find another reason for sample inefficiency of model-free on-policy Deep Reinforcement Learning?

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, sample-efficiency, sample-complexity

The following mindmap gives an overview of multiple reasons for sample inefficiency. The list is definitely not complete. Can you see another reason not mentioned so far?

[image]

Some related links:

- [interactive mindmap](https://coggle.it/diagram/XsAi9ZnPdIGARTN0/t/reasons-for-sample-inefficiency-of-on-policy-deep-rl/fae93aa14ab81e96310145594778527a7cee5bee454782e355477fc83603278f)
- [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/reinforcementlearning/comments/gqtq40/have_we_caught_em_all_can_you_find_another_reason/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) asking the same question
- [related SE question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/18645/35821) with only a few reasons all mentioned here